# IOS Charts - YAxis scaling number round to nearest hundred, thousands, etc

Tags: ios, swift, swift5, ios-charts

Is there a way with the iOs Charts lib (3.6.0) to scale the Y axis with the nearest hundred, thousands, etc ?

I'm probably missing something but my Y axis doesn't make any sense :

[image]

In this exemple, I would like my Y axis to be something like :

```
75 000
60 000
45 000
30 000
15 000
0
-15 000
```

I tried using `autoScaleMinMaxEnabled`but it doesn't seem to work.

I don't understand how to make the y axis use rounded numbers ?

Thank you for your help

Update :

Here is the code I use, as requested :

```swift
class GraphCustomView : LineChartView, ChartViewDelegate {
    //MARK: Variables
    var graphModel: [GraphModel] = []
    
    // Initialize Chart
    public func initializeChart(graphModel: [GraphModel], devise: String, withouthFill: Bool? = true) {
        self.graphModel = [GraphModel]()
        self.graphModel = graphModel
        
        self.delegate = self
        self.chartDescription?.enabled = false
                
        // xAxis
        self.xAxis.enabled = true
        self.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
        self.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
        self.xAxis.valueFormatter = DateValueFormatter(miniTime: graphModel.first!.miniDate)
        self.xAxis.labelFont = UIFont(name: "Ubuntu", size: 8)!
        self.xAxis.labelRotationAngle = -20
        self.xAxis.granularityEnabled = true
        self.xAxis.granularity = 1
        
        // RightAxis
        self.rightAxis.enabled = false
        self.rightAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
        
        // LeftAxis
        self.leftAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = true
        self.leftAxis.gridColor = .gray
        self.leftAxis.gridLineDashLengths = [CGFloat(1.5)]
        self.leftAxis.labelFont = UIFont(name: "Ubuntu", size: 8)!
        
        // General chart settings
        self.drawBordersEnabled = false
        self.setScaleEnabled(true)
        
        leftAxis.setLabelCount(7, force: true)
        leftAxis.drawTopYLabelEntryEnabled = true
        leftAxis.drawBottomYLabelEntryEnabled = true
               
        // Legend
        self.leftAxis.labelFont = UIFont(name: "Ubuntu", size: 11)!
        self.xAxis.labelFont = UIFont(name: "Ubuntu", size: 11)!
        
        let l = self.legend
        l.form = .circle
        l.horizontalAlignment = .right
        l.verticalAlignment = .bottom
        l.orientation = .horizontal
        l.drawInside = false
        l.font = UIFont(name: "Ubuntu", size: 8)!
        
        // Overdrawn line
        let minValue = graphModel.first!.minValue
        let maxValue = graphModel.first!.maxValue
        var range: Double = 0.0
        
        if (maxValue - minValue != 0) {
            range = (maxValue - minValue) / 7
        }
        
        if (graphModel.first!.minValue - (range * 2) < graphModel.first!.overdrawn && graphModel.first!.overdrawn < graphModel.first!.minValue) {
            self.leftAxis.axisMinimum = graphModel.first!.overdrawn
        }
                                
        let limit: ChartLimitLine = ChartLimitLine()
        limit.label = "Overdrawn"
        limit.limit = graphModel.first!.overdrawn
        limit.valueTextColor = .red
        limit.lineColor = .red
        limit.lineDashLengths = [10, 5]
        leftAxis.addLimitLine(limit)
        
        // Marker/Tooltip
        let marker = XYMarkerView(color: .darkGray,
                                  font: UIFont(name: "Ubuntu", size: 12)!,
                                  textColor: .white,
                                  insets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 8, bottom: 20, right: 8),
                                  xAxisValueFormatter: DateValueFormatter(miniTime: graphModel.first!.miniDate),
                                  yAxisValueFormatter: MarkerValueFormatter(devise: devise))
        marker.chartView = self
        marker.minimumSize = CGSize(width: 80, height: 40)
        self.marker = marker
        
        self.isMultipleTouchEnabled = true
        self.highlightPerTapEnabled = true
        self.highlightPerDragEnabled = true
        
        // Add data to chart
        self.updateChartData()
    }
    
    public func updateChartData() {
        // Creating dataSets
        var dataSets: [LineChartDataSet] = [LineChartDataSet]()
        
        // We need to sort the data in order to add it to the graph
        for graph in self.graphModel {
            graph.chartData.sort(by: { $0.x < $1.x })
            
            let dataSet : LineChartDataSet = LineChartDataSet(entries: graph.chartData, label: graph.name)
            dataSet.circleRadius = 0
            dataSet.colors = graph.color
            dataSet.drawValuesEnabled = false
            dataSet.lineWidth = 2
            dataSet.mode = .cubicBezier

            let leftAxis = self.leftAxis
            leftAxis.drawLimitLinesBehindDataEnabled = true
            dataSet.fillColor = graph.color.first!
            dataSet.drawFilledEnabled = true
            
            // Add to datasets
            dataSets.append(dataSet)
        }
        
        // Styling data
        let data = LineChartData(dataSets: dataSets)
        data.setValueFont(UIFont(name: "Ubuntu", size: 7)!)
        
        // Displaying graph
        self.data = data
    }
```

Here is the data I used for this specific chart :

```json
[{\"pointDate\":\"2016-11-01T00:00:00\",\"pointValue\":45375.800000000003},{\"pointDate\":\"2016-11-01T00:00:00\",\"pointValue\":45375.800000000003},{\"pointDate\":\"2016-10-31T00:00:00\",\"pointValue\":54755.580000000002},{\"pointDate\":\"2016-10-30T00:00:00\",\"pointValue\":34324.199999999997},{\"pointDate\":\"2016-10-29T00:00:00\",\"pointValue\":43846.059999999998},{\"pointDate\":\"2016-10-28T00:00:00\",\"pointValue\":29243.779999999999},{\"pointDate\":\"2016-10-27T00:00:00\",\"pointValue\":28238.439999999999},{\"pointDate\":\"2016-10-26T00:00:00\",\"pointValue\":-11461.74},{\"pointDate\":\"2016-10-25T00:00:00\",\"pointValue\":-5756.5500000000002},{\"pointDate\":\"2016-10-24T00:00:00\",\"pointValue\":27565.939999999999},{\"pointDate\":\"2016-10-23T00:00:00\",\"pointValue\":40770.910000000003},{\"pointDate\":\"2016-10-22T00:00:00\",\"pointValue\":46875.870000000003},{\"pointDate\":\"2016-10-21T00:00:00\",\"pointValue\":44609.540000000001},{\"pointDate\":\"2016-10-20T00:00:00\",\"pointValue\":43970.769999999997},{\"pointDate\":\"2016-10-19T00:00:00\",\"pointValue\":43262.910000000003},{\"pointDate\":\"2016-10-18T00:00:00\",\"pointValue\":22016.080000000002},{\"pointDate\":\"2016-10-17T00:00:00\",\"pointValue\":45001.940000000002},{\"pointDate\":\"2016-10-16T00:00:00\",\"pointValue\":44443.739999999998},{\"pointDate\":\"2016-10-15T00:00:00\",\"pointValue\":61521.720000000001},{\"pointDate\":\"2016-10-14T00:00:00\",\"pointValue\":31674.16},{\"pointDate\":\"2016-10-13T00:00:00\",\"pointValue\":42767.040000000001},{\"pointDate\":\"2016-10-12T00:00:00\",\"pointValue\":55202.110000000001},{\"pointDate\":\"2016-10-11T00:00:00\",\"pointValue\":76274.100000000006},{\"pointDate\":\"2016-10-10T00:00:00\",\"pointValue\":39097.07},{\"pointDate\":\"2016-10-09T00:00:00\",\"pointValue\":13742.99},{\"pointDate\":\"2016-10-08T00:00:00\",\"pointValue\":9616.2199999999993},{\"pointDate\":\"2016-10-07T00:00:00\",\"pointValue\":1450.6099999999999},{\"pointDate\":\"2016-10-06T00:00:00\",\"pointValue\":5820.5},{\"pointDate\":\"2016-10-05T00:00:00\",\"pointValue\":-9522.75},{\"pointDate\":\"2016-10-04T00:00:00\",\"pointValue\":8317},{\"pointDate\":\"2016-10-03T00:00:00\",\"pointValue\":7923.6499999999996},{\"pointDate\":\"2016-10-02T00:00:00\",\"pointValue\":10249.889999999999},{\"pointDate\":\"2016-10-01T00:00:00\",\"pointValue\":2388.6799999999998},{\"pointDate\":\"2016-09-30T00:00:00\",\"pointValue\":0}]
```

And the code use to format it a bit :

```swift
for point in pointevo.pointEvolution {
    let date = point.pointDate.toDate()
    let timeInSecondes = date?.timeIntervalSince1970
                                    
    if (firstTime) {
        self.miniDate = timeInSecondes!
        firstTime = false
        
        minValue = point.pointValue
        maxValue = point.pointValue
    }
    
    if (point.pointValue < minValue) {
        minValue = point.pointValue
    }
    if (point.pointValue > maxValue) {
        maxValue = point.pointValue
    }
    
    chartData.append(ChartDataEntry(x: (timeInSecondes! - miniDate) / (3600.0 * 24.0), y: point.pointValue))
                        
    if tempPointValue.firstIndex(of: point.pointValue) == nil {
        tempPointValue.append(point.pointValue)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED AFTER DISCUSSIONS**

As I test your code with your data I found the root of your issue. In your code it's the line:

```
leftAxis.setLabelCount(7, force: true)
```

If *force* parameter is set to *true* - it override the default calculated labels and force the labels to be exact number of labels you specified and it will spread by equal distance.

If not *force* it - when there will be not exact number of labels specified, I got 6 lines (and labels). So it's now up to you how to better use it.

Here also examples of results if *force* parameter is **true** and **false** (I set here xaxis and overdraw values to some static values).

[image: force parameter is true]

[image: force parameter is false]

**Below the first one answer for some other situation.**

You can use for it *IAxisValueFormatter* protocol method *stringForValue(_ value:, axis:)*. You can round your value here and place additional symbols, like currencies symbol, like I do. Something like this:

```
extension ChartController: IAxisValueFormatter {

    func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {
        if axis is XAxis {
            // do something you need for X axis
            return valueTransformedToString
        } else {
            // do something you need for Y axis
            return valueTransformedToString
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I know about AxisValueFormatter but if I use it the graph won't be correct. For example, in the picture I added, if I change `-11 462` to `-15 000`, when the user will click on the point, the Y axis won't make any sense... Isn't there a way to work with ranges ?

Comment: It's interesting case. As I know Chart make it automatically. I just now look at my code (I wrote it a months ago, so don't remember everything) - and it works without any additional steps from my own. I tried to leave only the data setting to datasets - without any additional flags - and my y axis values are very good big whole numbers. Also look at examples and screens on Chart github page - these values are always good. So now it become even more interesting for me to understand how you achieve this, I tried to make it in my tests - and nothing similar :) Can you bring here a code you use?

Comment: about AxisValueFormatter you are right, it's not the case for this situation.

Comment: I added the code I use as an update to my question. I'm probably doing something wrong... Thank you for your help !

Comment: can you also add data you used? to be make more correct test... will try to use your code and see what happens here

Comment: I test your code and data and do some more research and found the root of your issue. I edit my original answer.

Comment: wow ok, a small parameter then... Thank you so much !!!!